# List not showing in card layout in 2.1.1 version. Working Perfectly in 2.0 version

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

IMPORTANT: THIS IS WORKING IN VERSION 2.0 AND NOT IN 2.1.1

My app has 2 different tabs at the bottom (near by, search)
Both this tab use the same list as given below.
Also both NearBy and Search use card layout, the only difference is in Near By the list is in the first card and for Search the list is in the Second card

i am trying this for last 2 day and no progress in this. Please help me

```
Ext.define('ChurchLookup.view.ChurchList', {
extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype: 'churchlist',


config:
{
    title: 'Zip Code',
    cls: 'x-contacts',
    grouped: true,
    store: 'Churches',
    itemTpl:
    [
        '<div class="headshot" style="background-image:url(resources/images/church-type-logo/{icon}.png);"></div>',
        '{name}, {city}',
        '<span>{phone} / {email}</span>'
    ].join('')
}});
```

For Near by when the tab is clicked the list will displayed inside the tab panel.
This is working perfectly and I can see the list.

**NEAR BY CARD CODE**

```
Ext.define('ChurchLookup.view.NearBy',
{
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'nearbycard',
    config:
    {
        iconCls: 'locate',
        title: 'Near By',
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        layout:
        {
              type: 'card',
              animation:
            {
                type: 'pop',
                duration: 500,
            }
        },
        items:
        [
            {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Near by Churches',
                items:
                [
                    {
                        itemId: 'btnBackNearBy',
                        text: "Back",
                        ui: "back",
                        hidden: true,
                        action:  'onBackNearBy'
                    }/*,
                    {
                        itemId: 'btnHomeSettings',
                        iconMask:true,
                        iconCls: 'settings',
                        ui:      'border',
                        align:   'right',
                        action:  'pingHomeBadge'
                    }*/
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'churchlist'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'churchdetailsnearby'
            }
        ],
        listeners:
        [
            {
                delegate: "#btnHomeSettings",
                event: "tap",
                fn: "onHomeScreenSettings"
            },
            {
                delegate: "#btnBackNearBy",
                event: "tap",
                fn: "onBackNearBy"
            }
        ]
    },
    onHomeScreenSettings: function ()
    {
        this.fireEvent("homeScreenSettings", this);
    },
    onBackNearBy: function ()
    {
        this.fireEvent("onBackNearBy", this);
    }
});
```

But for the search when we click the "Search" tab it will show a card layout with 2 card.
The frist card is the search form and the second card is the list.
When the user fill the form and click the search button I just load the store and change the card layout to show the list.
But the card layout is showing the second page but not the list.

**SEARCH TAB CODE**

```
Ext.define('ChurchLookup.view.Search',
{
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'searchcard',
    config:
    {
        iconCls: 'search',
        title: 'Search',
          scrollable: 'vertical',
        layout:
        {
              type: 'card',
              animation:
            {
                type: 'pop',
                duration: 500,
            }
        },
        items:
        [
            {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Search Church',
                items:
                [
                    {
                        itemId: 'btnBackSearch',
                        text: "Back",
                        ui: "back",
                        hidden: true,
                        action:  'onBackSearch'
                    }/*,
                    {
                        itemId: 'btnHomeSettings',
                        iconMask:true,
                        iconCls: 'settings',
                        ui:      'border',
                        align:   'right',
                        action:  'pingHomeBadge'
                    }*/
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'searchform'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'favouritecard'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'churchdetailssearch'
            }
        ],
        listeners:
        [
            {
                delegate: "#btnHomeSettings",
                event: "tap",
                fn: "onHomeScreenSettings"
            },
            {
                delegate: "#btnBackSearch",
                event: "tap",
                fn: "onBackSearch"
            }
        ]
    },
    onHomeScreenSettings: function ()
    {
        this.fireEvent("homeScreenSettings", this);
    },
    onBackSearch: function ()
    {
        this.fireEvent("onBackSearch", this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe height problem.

Is 'churchdetailssearch' the same as 'churchlist' ?

If churchdetailssearch' has toolbar or something set layout :'vbox' to 'churchdetailssearch', and add the list of 'churchdetailssearch' flex : 1.

Maybe useful the page.
[Explain how to a scrollable List use dynamic height without fixed height](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?184110-Explain-how-to-a-scrollable-List-use-dynamic-height-without-fixed-height)